# PHP algorithm for finding people with same interests

Tags: php, mysql

In my MySql i have `Interests` column that stores interests of user.That row varies from simple `Readng` to  `Astronomy,Dancing,Engineering,Fashion,Iceskating,Music,Painting,Puzzles,Singing,Yoga,Gardening,Reading`.
My goal is to find people that share same interests as user does.
Here is my code

```
$selhobbies=$con->query("SELECT Interests FROM user_opt WHERE Username='$NameId'");
$Users_hobbies=$selhobbies->fetch_row();
$query=$con->query("SELECT Username FROM user_opt WHERE Interests LIKE '%{$Users_hobbies[0]}%'") or die($con->error);
```

Now if `User_hobbies` is `Reading,Music` it won't find guy whose hobby is only `Reading`.How can i fix that?

Comment: If you want to run a query like this, then fix your data structure.  Create a table with one interest for each user per row.

Comment: I have 136 Interests @GordonLinoff

Comment: So 136 rows. Fine.

Answer (score 0):

I did it with exploding `User_hobbies` like this

```
$explode=explode(',',$Users_hobbies[0]);
for ($i=0; $i <=$come_count; $i++) { 
    $query.="UNION
             SELECT Username FROM user_opt WHERE Interests LIKE '%".$explode[$i]."%'";
}
$run=$con->query($query) or die($con->error);
```